# Unable to receive Bluetooth events for a Xamarin.ios app when the app is in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, background-process, core-bluetooth, uibackgroundmode

I am building a Xamarin.ios application which uses Bluetooth connectivity. I am trying to achieve below things.

1. Whenever my app is pushed to background, the app still need to receive the Bluetooth events.
   For this, I have included these strings into info.plist

   ```
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
     <string>bluetooth-central</string>
     <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>
   ```
2. Whenever my app is in background, Bluetooth events are not being received

   a] No events seen with CBCentralManager interface

   b] No events seen in AppDelegates also.

Please let me know, on how to receive these events

3. The other scenario that I am trying to achieve is automatic launch of App whenever the Bluetooth device is connected. Is there a way to achieve this? if yes, please share the steps.